# Best way to show one Bayesian model is more certain and accurate than another, based on simulated data?

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, scoring-rules, credible-interval, probabilistic-programming

I'm trying to compare performance of two bayesian models $A$ and $B$ on simulated data. It's a recruitment curve fitting problem and I'm interested in how accurate these models are in estimating only one parameter of the curve, let's call that parameter $q$.

I run $10$ trials (10 different simulations). For every trial, I have the true value for $q$, as well as the HPDI credible intervals and MAP estimates for $q$ from models $A$ and $B$.

Accuracy: The naive way would be to compare these models based on mean absolute error or mean squared error between their MAP estimates and true values of $q$, but I feel like this is not very Bayesian. I'd like to use credible intervals instead. Is it possible to come up with a metric which uses credible intervals? I want to quantify how reliable model A's credible interval is to model B's.

Uncertainity: The naive (and possibly incorrect) way would be to measure the length of their credible intervals -- but one could could have a tighter interval and not contain the true estimate.

Ideally, I would like to come up with a metric that combines both accuracy and uncertainity.

Is there any existing theory/research on this? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You may want to consider how likely the empirical curve is under each Bayesian model, adding a penalty term for model complexity a la [AIC](http://stanfordphd.com/AIC.html) or [BIC](http://stanfordphd.com/BIC.html).

Comment: The Root Mean Square Error, I wouldn't consider it naive, since it takes into account both bias and variability.  But in order to be more confident to answer your question, we would need more information about the formulations of both models.

Comment: As stated in the question's tags, a scoring rule would probably be helpful for your problem. However, you would need the full a posteriori distributions of the two models in order to use them. Is this possible in your setting?